# How to pivot table without aggregation functions in pyspark

Tags: pivot-table, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this in pyspark.

```
|--------------|----------------|---------------|
|   col_1      |     col_2      |   col_3       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       1      |       A        |     abd       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       1      |       B        |     acd       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       1      |       A        |     bcd       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       1      |       B        |     ceg       |
------------------------------------------------|
|       2      |       A        |     cgs       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       2      |       B        |     bsc       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       2      |       A        |     iow       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

I would like to pivot table into this.

```
|--------------|----------------|---------------|
|   col_1      |       A        |      B        |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       1      |       abd      |     acd       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       1      |       bcd      |     ceg       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       2      |       cgs      |     bsc       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|       2      |       iow      |     null      |
------------------------------------------------|
```

How shall I do this? The pivot function for pyspark dataframe requires aggregate function and in my case `col_1` is not unique either.

Answer (score 0):

Here a way where you could get your target result :

```
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F

    df = df.groupBy('col_1').pivot("col_2").agg(F.collect_list("col_3"))

    cols = df.columns[1:]
    res = df.select("col_1",F.explode(cols[0]).alias(cols[0])).withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

    for name in cols[1:]:
        res = res.join(df.select("col_1",F.explode(name).alias(name)).withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id()),on = ["id","col_1"], how = "outer")

    res = res.orderBy("col_1").drop("id")
```

Comment: I tried your approach, the results do not seem correct. I think the problem is probably there are missing ABAB. For instance for `id = 2`, there is one B missing. If there are other data for `id = 3` afterwards, how would id through monotonically_increasing_id() account for that? Could you please maybe show how it works step by step, show the results after each step in your code?